# Multi-dimensional (2D) array dynamically using malloc()?

Tags: c, arrays

Please if someone tell me what is wrong with this code by using malloc function, I dont know what to do.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <string.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <process.h>

 int main()
 {
 int row;
 int column;
 int j=0;
 int **ptr;

 printf("Number of rows: \n");
 scanf ("%d",&row);
 printf("Number of columns: \n"); 
 scanf ("%d",&column);
```

There is a mistake, ???? please if someone know what to do to write

```
 int* ptr = malloc( row * sizeof(*ptr) ); /*Allocate integer pointers for the rows */
    if(ptr != NULL)
    {
        for(int m = 0; m < row; m++) /* Loop through each row pointer to allocate     memory for columns*/
        {
            /* Set p[i] pointer to a block of memory for 'column' number of integers */
            ptr[m] = malloc(column * sizeof **ptr); /*Here, sizeof(**p) is same as sizeof(int) */
            if(ptr[m] == NULL)
            {
                printf("Memory allocation failed. Exiting....");
                 exit(1);  
            }
        }

    }
    else
    {
        printf("Memory allocation failed. Exiting....");
         exit(1);  
    }





for(int i=0; i<row; i++)
{
   for(int j=0; j<column; j++)
{
printf("Enter values [%d] [%d]: \n",i+1,j+1 );  
scanf ("%d",&ptr[i][j]);
}
}


free (ptr); 
system("PAUSE");    
return 0;
}
```

Pleas for answer because i need this code in school till 3. Jan. 2014

Comment: Remove the `int *ptr` from your initial alloc. You're already declaring it as `int **ptr;` in the prior declaration. This: `int* ptr = malloc( row * sizeof(*ptr) );` should be this: `ptr = malloc( row * sizeof(*ptr) );`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

First off your code is very messy. Your malloc call should also look like this for example:

```
   int** ptr = (int**)malloc(row * sizeof(ptr*));
```

The size of a pointer will always (almost all the time unless you are on a computer made in 1982) be 4 because its a memory address aka an int wich is 4 bytes. In your for loop it should read something like:

```
    ptr[m] = (int*)malloc(column * sizeof(ptr));
```

Comment: Please, don't teach to cast the return from `malloc`, this is C and not C++. The original code had it right on that point, you now got it wrong.

Comment: `sizeof(ptr*}` is incorrect syntax; it should be `sizeof *ptr`. And, in the assignment to `ptr[m]`, `sizeof(ptr)` is incorrect; it should be `sizeof *ptr[m]`.

Comment: The size of a pointer is neither always four bytes nor always the size of an `int`.

Comment: @JensGustedt If casting malloc is wrong then how come thats what i see for examples almost every example of malloc? What exactly is wrong with doing that?

Comment: @Katianie, probably because you are looking at examples that are written for C++ and not for C. The top of the FAQ here on SO for C is the one that you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc

Comment: @EricPostpischil sizeof is a function and thus I call it as a function. I don't see why you would want to write it in that style. Also for complexity sake i went with int is almost always 4 because its never been otherwise for me.

Comment: @Katianie: `sizeof` is an operator, not a function (per C 2011 clause 6.5.3.4). However, the important part of my comment is not the parentheses but the syntax of the first operand and the correctness of the second. `ptr*` is not a valid expression or type name; `*ptr` is correct. And `sizeof(ptr)` for the second operand allocates memory for `ptr` objects, but the memory is intended to be used for objects pointed to be `ptr[m]`, hence `*ptr[m]`. Using `sizeof(ptr)` will allocate the wrong amount of space in implementations where an `int **` has a different size than an `int`.

Comment: @Katianie: The fact that an `int` has never been other than four bytes to you is irrelevant to whether it always is. The statement that an `int` is always four bytes is false.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Sorry for trying to make his life easier.

Answer (score 3):

Change this line…

```
int* ptr = malloc( row * sizeof(*ptr) );
```

… to this…

```
ptr = malloc( row * sizeof(*ptr) );
```

You've already declared `ptr` here:

```
int **ptr;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you feel the *need* to use `malloc` (and `free`) for dynamic allocation, then there are some good answers already here.  But please consider that you do not need to use `malloc` at all in your example.

You can simply declare an automatic array of variable size as shown below.  Your code will be very clear and the potential for bugs will be reduced.  This feature is available in the C language since ISO C99 (earlier, in some compliers).

There can be an argument to not use variable sized array declaration *if* the array will be extremely large.  Your example is taking user input for each array element, so that tells me you're not allocating hundreds of megabytes or anything that would blow up the stack!  So this will work for you just fine.  Good luck.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int rows;
    int columns;

    printf("Number rows: ");
    scanf ("%d", &rows);
    printf("Stevilo columns: "); 
    scanf ("%d", &columns);  

    int values[rows][columns];   /* <-- no need to malloc(), no need to free() */

    for(int i=0; i<rows; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<columns; j++) {
            printf("Enter value[%d][%d]: ",i+1,j+1 );  
            scanf("%d", &values[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `sizeof (ptr)` and `sizeof **ptr`, try to use `sizeof(int*)` in the first malloc, and `sizeof(int)` in the second malloc.

Comment: The op's sizing for this is correct. Also, `sizeof(*int)` isn't even valid C code.

Comment: `sizeof(*ptr)` and `sizeof(**ptr)` are identical to `sizeof(int *)` and `sizeof(int)`, respectively, in this case.

Answer (score 0):

thank you all for so fast answers, it was very helpful, now it works without any error!

I did so:

```
    int** ptr = (int**) malloc(row * sizeof(int)); /*Allocate integer pointers for the rows */
    if(ptr != NULL)
    {
        for(int m = 0; m < row; m++) /* Loop through each row pointer to allocate memory for columns*/
        {
            /* Set p[i] pointer to a block of memory for 'column' number of integers */
            ptr[m] = (int*)malloc(column * sizeof(int)); /*Here, sizeof(**p) is same as sizeof(int) */
            if(ptr[m] == NULL)
            {
                printf("Memory allocation failed. Exiting....");
                 exit(1);  
            }
        }

    }
    else
    {
        printf("Memory allocation failed. Exiting....");
         exit(1);  
    }
```

Comment: `int** ptr = (int**) malloc(row * sizeof(int));` uses the wrong size. It should be `row * sizeof *ptr`.